# How to check array<object,N> size, with N a natural number?

Tags: .net, arrays, c++-cli

My question is simple. How can I know the size of an array declared as...?

```
array<ObjectType^, 3>
```

I've seen that the access to their elements is made by the next way:

```
array_var[i,j,k];
```

So, how can I know the size of the different dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using a managed array in c++/cli (though as of time of writing, you haven't got round to confirming this yet).

On the assumption that you *are* using a `cli::array` instance, you can see from [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4c4dw6(v=vs.100).aspx) that it inherits from `System::Array`, and all methods of that class are applicable. If you read that class' [own documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), you'll find that there's an `Array::GetLength(Int32)` method that lets you get the size of a given dimension (see that method's documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx)).

For example,

```
array<ObjectType^, 3>^ array_var = gcnew array<ObjectType^, 3>(3, 4, 5);
```

declares a new 3d array of size`3*4*5`.

```
array_var->GetLength(2)
```

will return `5` (because the dimensions are numbered from 0, as usual). You can also use `array_var->Rank` to get the number of dimensions for the array.

Comment: Great! This worked! And Rank method also was so useful to me!

Answer (score -1):

**ASSUMING YOU'RE USING C++ STD::ARRAYS AND NOT .NET ARRAYS**

That is not how std::array works. That wouldn't be a 3D array (based on what code you've given). It'd actually be a 1D array.

So your code would actually end up looking something like this (in pseudocode):

```
std::array<int, 3> array_var;
sizeof(array_var[i]) * sizeof(int);
```

This should work. As for each dimension. Well, you can do this

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>, 3> test;

sizeof(test[i][0][0]) * sizeof(int);
sizeof(test[0][j][0]) * sizeof(int);
sizeof(test[0][0][k]) * sizeof(int);
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way (trust me, its not), I'm pretty sure more experienced programmers will be able to conclude better ways. But here you go!!

By the way, I'm sorry if this didn't answer your question. I didn't really understand, but I still took a stab.

Comment: @Rook so this is .net hes talking about? I figured, due to the ^, my bad by the way, I forgot to fix my post.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what the OP was talking about, but it might be best to wait til they've clarified before answering ;-)

Comment: @Rook True, I'm truly sorry!! I'm new to SO :)

Comment: Hi Graham. I'm not sure if it is .NET array or C++ array because my Visual Studio must have some problem when trying to show classes (its internal linker don't tell me what's the origin class of an object). Any trick for finding classes works to me (placing mouse over object, going to definition, ...). That's the reason I had to ask this question instead of consulting the API.